# How to check matching pixels in image in java?

Tags: java, image-processing, pixel

I want to read image into pixels and want to check the matching pixel values and do some  processing and convert the processed pixels into image. I have

```
Pixel Location(582,131)- [Alpha: 255, Red: 243, Green: 88, Blue: 146]

Pixel Location(582,132)- [Alpha: 255, Red: 244, Green: 86, Blue: 145]

Pixel Location(582,133)- [Alpha: 255, Red: 245, Green: 87, Blue: 146]


Pixel Location(582,134)- [Alpha: 255, Red: 248, Green: 90, Blue: 149]

Pixel Location(582,135)- [Alpha: 255, Red: 250, Green: 92, Blue: 151]

Pixel Location(582,136)- [Alpha: 255, Red: 251, Green: 91, Blue: 151]

Pixel Location(582,137)- [Alpha: 255, Red: 248, Green: 88, Blue: 148]

Pixel Location(582,138)- [Alpha: 255, Red: 248, Green: 88, Blue: 148]
```

these pixels values. Now I want to know how to compare these values with one another to get the matching pixels.

And convert the processed image pixel values into image

```
    public static void pixels(String args) {

    BufferedImage image = readImage(args);


    printAllARGBDetails(image);
       }

       public static void printAllARGBDetails(BufferedImage image) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    System.out.println("Image Dimension: Height-" + height + ", Width-"
            + width);
    System.out.println("Total Pixels: " + (height * width));
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {

            int pixel = image.getRGB(i, j);
            System.out.println("Pixel Location(" + i + "," + j + ")- ["
                    + getARGBPixelData(pixel) + "]");
        }
    }
}

public static String getARGBPixelData(int pixel) {
    String pixelARGBData = "";

    int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0x000000FF;



    int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0x000000FF;


    int green = (pixel >>8 ) & 0x000000FF;


    int blue = (pixel) & 0x000000FF;

    pixelARGBData = "Alpha: " + alpha + ", " + "Red: " + red + ", "
            + "Green: " + green + ", " + "Blue: " + blue;

    return pixelARGBData;
}


public static BufferedImage readImage(String fileLocation)
    {
    BufferedImage img = null;

    try 
   {

        img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileLocation));

   } 

   catch (IOException e) 

   {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return img;


}
```

Comment: What format is the pixel data in? Typically you find them in packed int format

Comment: Are you matching across images, or within this one image?  If in same image, matching a single pixel's value with another, or a set of (relatively placed) pixels?  For image processing in Java, I'd recommend looking into BufferedImage, as you can read individual pixels and also build an image from pixels.

Comment: How did you get these values? Please show us some code.

Comment: @Junuxx I gave the code

Comment: "check the matching pixel values and do some processing" <-- More specifically...??  Do you have a starting known pixel area (like the 582,131-138 range shown) that you want to match? Or a specific pixel (ARGB) *value* that you're looking for in the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class like [pixel](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~i101/doc/Pixel.html) and doing overriding of compare with some fast algorithm as the one shown in [Fast and quick pixel matching algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187982/fast-and-quick-pixel-matching-algorithm).